# Check Facebook login status using Alloy or Titanium in an iOS app

Tags: facebook, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to add Facebook login to my Alloy/ Titanium ios app.

So far I have the following code:

```
var fb = require('facebook');
fb.initialize();
fb.setLoginBehavior(fb.LOGIN_BEHAVIOR_NATIVE);
fb.permissions = ['email', 'public_profile'];

function doFacebookLogin() {
    // occurs when a button is clicked
    if (fb.loggedIn) {
        facebookLogin(fb);
    } else {
        fb.authorize(); 
    }
}

fb.addEventListener('login', function(event) {  
    if (event.success) {
        facebookLogin(fb);
    }
});

function facebookLogin(fb) {
    Ti.API.info(fb.accessToken);
    // send the fb.accessToken server-side and register & login the user
}
```

For the most part the code works fine!

The issue is when the user de-authorises the app, `fb.login` still return `true` and so is using the same access token.

How can I check if the user has de-authorised my app. I know it's easily possible using the JavaScript SDK using `FB.getLoginStatus`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus , but I can't find an equivalent in Alloy/Titanium: https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `fb.logout()` to set `fb.loggedIn to false`.

`fb.logout` clears the access token and resets the login state to false.

Note: I am not sure whether clearing the access token in Titanium module will also clear the token on FB server. So even after calling `fb.logout()`, you might receive the same access token if and only if it has not expired on fb server.

Read more about **[Facebook Access Token here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens)**

Comment: That was the original way I did things. However that only helps if the user deauthorised my application. If the user haven't deauthorised my application and I do this, it gives me a message saying "this application has already been authorised by the user". Hence, I need to find a way to check the login status of the user.

Comment: This is the normal procedure to implement FB. All Titanium apps use same flow and even native apps. I just checked Candy Crush game on my Android device and it's Facebook implementation is exactly same as in Titanium. 

Besides, I do not think that it's possible to do what you want because that message **"this application has already been authorised by the user"** is handled and shown by Facebook, not by the SDK or module.